# Local DNS on Amazon AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, hosts

I have an app running on a Linux server that makes use of external services that often don't have public DNS for their domain name.

To solve this I add local DNS to my `/etc/hosts` file - matching the IP address of the service to the domain name. This means we can use the domain name and the SSL certificate:

```
123.456.789.123    subdomain.domain.tld
```

However we're moving this app to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup, so we can't make use of the traditional `/etc/hosts` method.

I've been trying to research this in the Amazon docs, but I'm either Googling the wrong thing or they don't offer such functionality.

Any ideas?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're deployed in a VPC and you're using AWS Route53 to manage your domain's DNS, you can create a "Private Hosted Zone" (DNS split view) with the private addresses and associate it with the VPC.  Note that you can only use the private zone or the public zone; if there are records in the public zone that are not in the private zone, the DNS lookup will fail.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html